# Draw when called

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I'm trying to draw a table of colors (already constructed) to a selected area in my window.
I'm currently learning from [this](http://www.zetcode.com/gui/winapi/gdi/) source. However, in all of the given code examples, the draw is being carried out as soon as the window is opened.

What should I do if I want the drawing to occur when I click a menu item, or just not in the beginning?

**EDIT:**

I created a new window called `GifPanel` which will be drawn.

My variables:

```
HWND GifPanel;
RECT r;
```

my `GifPanelProc:`

```
case WM_PAINT:
    DrawFrame(GifPanel); // DrawFrame uses BeginPaint, SetPixel, EndPaint in order to draw
    break;
```

Next, I have a function that by click does the following:

```
GetClientRect(GifPanel, &r);
InvalidateRect(GifPanel, &r, FALSE);
```

When first opening the window, I can see that `GifPanel` has a red background (just to test it is working).

After executing the process above, no pixels are changed. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A window is required to draw itself whenever it receives a `WM_PAINT` message; typically it will get a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message first to erase the background. If you don't want to draw your table you need to keep a flag that you can test in your `WM_PAINT` handler to skip the drawing of the table.

In your menu handler, first set the flag and then use [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to cause the `WM_PAINT` message to be generated.

Comment: Could you please review my edit? I'm having a bit of a trouble implementing your solution.

Comment: Do some debugging. What little you have shown looks OK, but you have not shown the code that does the painting. Does that code execute? Have you tried having it draw a rectangle so you can see the coordinates it is using?